# Expendable list view icon removed but still taking a empty space

Tags: android, android-listview

I Have a expendable list view I removed the icon but still the space is empty

[image]

how to remove the space.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DirectorActivity" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/heading_textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent">
</ExpandableListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also face this issue and i have apply `android:groupIndicator="@null"` but it was not worked for me.

I think that is only `hide the Icon` at that place it is not removing the icon.

So i have follow [some other example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/) and edit that code as per my requirement.

Please try it once hope it will works for you.